# Adding icons to my buttons on a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog where I use some buttons inside a table (for edit/delete functionalities).

I am able to add icons on these buttons **only if I code an alert just before**. Very strange. If I remove the alert, buttons are not showed.

[image]

```
$().ready(function () {

    $('.MaterialEdit').live("click", function () {
        alert('clicked');
        $(".MaterialPackingEdit").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-pencil"} });
        $(".MaterialPackingRemove").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash"} });    
    });
});
```

The MaterialEdit class used above correspond to a button on my main page to open the jQuery dialog.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `$(document).ready(function(){...})` which is equivalent to `$(function() {...})`

Comment: @jb10210: I try and it doesn't change anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Unless you are creating the buttons during your click event, you should move the button initialization code into your document ready function, not the click. Do you have any JavaScript errors from your browser?

Comment: can you show more code on how you create the dialog? Your button code should work correctly, but I would suggest initializing them only once (using `once(...)`) instead of on each click of the dialog button. And make sure that the buttons are initialized before the dialog is created otherwise you could indeed end up with this kind of weird behavior!

Comment: @lthibodeaux: you have to know that my jQuery dialog is loaded after the main page is loaded. The content of this jQuery dialog is loaded like this: $(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {....

Comment: Just make sure that before the call `.dialog(...)` your buttons are initialized and everything should be fine!

Comment: @jb10210: buttons are initialized at the same time of the .dialog(...) like this: $(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {.... as you can see, the .load is used for loading a page inside the jQuery and my buttons are located inside this loaded page.

Comment: Ok but the actual `.button(...)` call which initializes the buttons with their icons and other stuff should be done before the `.dialog(...)` call, you are talking about the `html` initialization not the actual `jQuery` calls. From your code snippet and comments it is not at all clear in which order what is executed, if ever ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some markup in the question would definitely have helped. Anyways, here's something that works on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/e3pCL/

The idea is to use the 'open' event as documented in the [dialog demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) like so:

```
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.MaterialPackingEdit').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-pencil"
            },
            text: false
        });
        $('.MaterialPackingRemove').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-trash"
            },
            text: false
        });
    }
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: for the function itself to be passed in to the generic 'dialog loader' function OP mentions in the comment, the below snippet could be used:

```
$(function() {
    var onDialogOpen = function(event, ui) {
            $('.MaterialPackingEdit').button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-pencil"
                },
                text: false
            });
            $('.MaterialPackingRemove').button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-trash"
                },
                text: false
            });
        };
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title:'Buttons As Icons on a jQuery Dialog',
        width: 400,
        open: onDialogOpen
    });
    $('.MaterialEdit').click(function() {
        $('.dialog').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Check this update to the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/e3pCL/27/

Comment: Thanks it help me much. Question: is it possible to have the function dynamic? I mean I have a generic DialogLoader where I pass several parameters (like width, height, ...) maybe I can pass the function name for the loading event? Possible?

Comment: Definitely. An onOpen callback function could be passed in as a parameter to your `DialogLoader` function and used in the dialog initialization. Check the update to the answer